# .scroll() not working like it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

So I'm trying to make my header appear when the page is scrolled down and I thought I could do that with a simple if statement. However, the way I did it, it doesn't 'monitor' the scrolling action. What I mean is that it automatically sets the height of the header to 0 and nothing else, it doesn't do anything when the page is scrolled down.

How can I rewrite this to set the height of the header to 0 when the top scroll position is 0 and to set the height to 80px when scrolled down to a certain degree?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        if ($(window).scroll(0)) {
            $( '#header' ).css( 'height', '0' );
        }
        else{
            $( '#header' ).css( 'height', '82px' );     
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scroll it:

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('header').hide();
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   if ($(window).scrollTop()<56){
    $('header').hide();
   }else{
    $('header').show();
   }
  });
 });
```

```css
 header{
  background:#222;
  height:56px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
 }
 body{
  height:3000px
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).scroll(...` will attach an event listener to the scroll event or trigger the scroll event, depending on the parameters passed. It is not at all used to obtain the current scrolled position of the element (in the given scenario, it would always return the `window` jQuery object, which is *always* truthy.)

What I believe you are looking to do is the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
        $( '#header' ).css( 'height', '0' );
    }
    else{
        $( '#header' ).css( 'height', '82px' );     
    }
});
```

`scrollTop()` returns the value, in pixels, that the (first) element has been scrolled. Which means if it equals 0, the element is scrolled to the top (or.. unscrolled)

Answer (score 1):

Just a little animation in case you find this helpful:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 82) {
      $("#header").css({
        "height": 0,
        "border-bottom": "none"
      });
    } else {
      $("#header").css({
        "height": "82px",
        "border-bottom": "1px solid #333"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

#content {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 5em; 
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h3>I'm a header</h3>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down</h3>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo purus, tempor id lobortis eget, pretium id lectus. Nam sed lorem quis velit efficitur gravida vel et enim. Ut laoreet sit amet enim ut tincidunt. Nunc vitae consectetur quam, ac varius
  est. Ut ac sagittis nisi. Etiam luctus ullamcorper eros. Nam molestie consectetur risus, ac accumsan velit cursus efficitur. Phasellus porta neque ut arcu rutrum facilisis. Proin non imperdiet ante. Vestibulum elit augue, cursus et nulla id, volutpat
  tincidunt ex. Nullam vitae nibh odio. Curabitur convallis sapien sit amet hendrerit vulputate. Phasellus sagittis suscipit augue nec congue. Pellentesque condimentum, eros vel auctor dapibus, velit enim sagittis nibh, sit amet efficitur erat sapien
  ut turpis. Cras bibendum, ex ac elementum facilisis, neque libero lobortis nulla, id molestie lectus ex at felis. Praesent ut elementum dui, et vestibulum ipsum. Quisque in mi scelerisque, pharetra sem in, pellentesque ipsum. Nam ultrices, diam ac consectetur
  viverra, nisl neque varius ante, vehicula semper ipsum velit at tellus. Sed velit massa, luctus id elit ut, volutpat rutrum erat. Nulla eu ipsum mauris. Etiam dictum viverra dui vel tempor.
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```